# Shapeless Generic, stratego-like strategic term rewriting, strongly typed with first class polymorphic functions doable?

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless, rewriting

I would like to find a way to build a Kiama like library with an added feature that would be to have strongly typed rewrite rules. (In Kiama eveyrything is a Term, and rewrite rules are  Term => Option[Term]

I know that shapeless allows to convert arbitrary case class hierarchies to a sum of products representation using hlists behind the scenes.

Based on this generic representation I imagine it could be fairly doable to write a generic library of traversal combinators (in the style of stratego) for applying rewrite rules on the generic version of a term made of nested case classe,

I have the feeling that it could be possible to use shapeless polyN functions to encode polymorphic term rewrite rules that would yield precise types, however these rewrite rules would have to operate on Hlists representing the case classes, which could be quite cumbersome to use compared to how pattern matching allows to match and transform sub trees

The simple example I have is this one

```
sealed abstract trait Expr { type Repr }
sealed abstract trait BoolExpr extends Expr { type Repr = Boolean }
sealed abstract trait IntExpr extends Expr { type Repr = Int }
case class BoolVar(sym: Symbol) extends BoolExpr
case class Not( l: BoolExpr ) extends BoolExpr
case class And( l: BoolExpr, r: IntExpr ) extends BoolExpr
case class Or( l: BoolExpr, r: IntExpr ) extends BoolExpr 
case class IntIte( cond: BoolExpr, thenExpr: IntExpr, elseExpr: IntExpr) extends IntExpr
case class IntConst( value: Int ) extends IntExpr
case class IntVar( sym: Symbol ) extends IntExpr

rule1 { case Not(Not(e)) => Some(e) }

rule2 { case IntIte(Not(c), t, e) => Some( IntIte(c, e, t) }
```

however, I fear that the rewrite rules would have to be expressed over hlists and hence I would loose the power of simple pattern matching as illustrated above. The only thing I can imagine is to, while traversing the shapeless.Generic structure, convert back bits of it  before matching a rule and convert back the result to generic and update the generic structure with the new term represented as a hlist.

Even better would be a rewriting system working on a GADT Expr[T] where T is the type of the expressions and rewrite rules would preserve that T.
Regards.

How feasible does this look to you?

Comment: Can't you use implicit resolution? E.g. write your rules as Shapeless `Poly`s?